# Firebase Cloudstore: how to "update all"/"delete some" docs in a collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

For context: I have a cron-job.org that fires an https function in my firebase project.

In this function, I have to go through all docs inside a collection and update a counter (each doc might have a different counter value). If the counter reaches a limit, I'll update another collection (independent from the first one), and delete the doc entry that reached the limit. If the counter is not beyond the limit, I simply update the doc entry with the updated counter value.

I tried adapting examples from the documentation, tried using transactions, batch, but I'm not sure how to proceed. According to transactions' description, that's the way to go, but examples only show how to edit a single doc.

This is what I have (tried adapting a realtime db sample):

```
function updateCounter() {
    var ref = db.collection('my_collection_of_counters');
    return ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            var docData = child.data();
            var newCounter = docData.counter+1;
            if (newCounter == 10) {
                // TO-DO: add to stock
                updates[child.key] = null;
            } else {
                docData.counter = newCounter;
                updates[child.key] = docData;   
            }
        });
        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        return ref.update(updates);
    });
}
```

It doesn't work, collections don't have an update method. What is the best approach to updating each doc in a collection? One-by-one? Transaction? Is there an example?

PS: updateCounter is a function being called by the https trigger. Cron+trigger is working fine.

**EDIT**
When an item reaches the threshold, I want to update another collection, independent from the counter one. Is nested transactions a good solution?

Modified code:

```
function updateCounter() {
    var ref = db.collection('my_collection_of_counters');
    var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(ref)
                .then(snapshot => {
                    let docs = snapshot.docs;
                    for (let doc of docs) {
                        var item = doc.data();
                        var newCounter = item.counter + 1;
                        if (newCounter == 10) {
                            console.log("Update my_stock");
                            // ADD item.quantity to stock collection
                        }else{
                            t.update(doc.ref, {counter: newCounter});
                        }
                    }
                });
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Transaction success');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noted yourself, you'll want to do this in a transaction to ensure that you can update the current counter value in a single operation.  You can also create the new document, and delete the existing one, in that same transaction once your counter reaches its threshold. I don't see any benefit of doing this for all documents in a single transaction, since the operation on each doc seems unrelated to the others.

In a Firestore transaction, you [perform the operations on a `Transaction` object as shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions). In your case you'd:

1. Get the current document with `transaction.get()`.
2. Get the counter from the document.
3. Increment the counter.
4. If the new value is below your threshold:

   1. Call `transaction.update()` to write the new counter value into the database
5. If the new value if above your threshold:

   1. Call `transaction.create` on the new collection to create the document there.
   2. Call `transaction.delete` on the existing document, to delete it.

For more, I recommend scanning the [reference documentation for the `Transaction` class](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/Transaction).

Comment: Progress! I was able to update each doc in the counter collection. Now your suggestion is to create an element in the other collection based on the completion of the one I just updated (i.e. threshold reached). However, I also want to update the other collection, not only create a new item. When the counter reaches the threshold, I want to ADD to the existing items in stock. Is it possible to use nested transactions? Would it be a good practice?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can nest transactions, but it shouldn't be needed anyway: your updating of the stock is the same transaction that read the existing counter and updates/deletes it.